# Cannot CTRL-C out of rabbitmq consumer console command

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

We recently upgraded from php 5.4 to 5.5 and we can no longer ctrl-c out of the consumer command. We start/stop the consumer every hour and this no longer works unless we send a SIGKILL which is not ideal.

```
 app/console rabbitmq:consumer ld_sync --env=dev
```

The command runs fine, it will consume messages, but will end up spiking one of our CPUs to 100%. It cannot be killed with ctrl-c. You must kill -9 it. I'm not even sure where to start debugging this issue. Even if you start it and try to ctrl-c immediately you cannot kill it.

I'd appreciate even a nudge in the right direction for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be solved with:
`app/console rabbitmq:consumer -w ld_sync --env=dev`

For `-w` option you need to have have enabled `pcntl` extension.

Comment: Thanks. We bandaged this with an interim solution but we still never had time to go back and solve it the right way. It might be a few days before I can try this out and award you the check mark.